# Выбрать несколько идущих подряд дат с определенным значением

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется следующая таблица c датами и количеством посетителей.

```
CREATE TABLE visit (
     id int PRIMARY KEY,
     visit_date date,
     people_count int
)
```

На каждый день приходится только одна запись о посещениях.
Как выбрать 3 и более подряд идущих дня, где количество посетителей было больше 100?
Частично решил при помощи островов:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate datetime;
SET @SomeDate = convert(datetime,'01.01.2000',104);

WITH [Islands] AS(
SELECT id, visit_date, people_count,
DATEDIFF(day, @SomeDate, visit_date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY visit_date) [island]
FROM visit)
SELECT * FROM Islands
WHERE people_count > 100
```

Далее их, наверное, можно было бы сгруппировать, но как выбрать именно 3 и более подряд идущих дней все равно не понимаю.

Comment: Подумайте, что вы получите, если для каждой даты, когда было МЕНЬШЕ 100 юзеров, выбрать БЛИЖАЙШУЮ следующую такую же дату...

Comment: @Akina Ну, допустим, 5го числа было 50 чел, 6го - 150 чел., 7го - 80 чел.
Шестое число оказывается между датами когда меньше 100 чел., но день только один, а нужно не менее трех подряд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть более универсальный вариант решения данной задачи. Сам принцип поиска непрерывной последовательности заключается в изначальной нумерации дат ( с учетом требования people_count > 100) и затем получения номера групп таких дат путем вычитания дня из даты (DATEPART) и полученного номера (ROW_NUMBER):

```
SELECT 
id,visit_date,people_count
 FROM
(
 SELECT id,visit_date,people_count,NumGroup,
 COUNT(visit_date)OVER (PARTITION BY NumGroup)CountREcords
 FROM
 (
  SELECT   --получаем номера групп с последовательно идущими датами
   id,visit_date,people_count,DATEADD(DAY,-Number,visit_date) AS NumGroup 
  FROM
   (
    SELECT id, people_count,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY visit_date)Number, visit_date  --нумеруем даты
      
   FROM
    ( 
    --осуществляем выборку нужных данных
     SELECT * FROM visit WHERE people_count>100     
    )A
  )B
 )C
)D
WHERE CountREcords>=3   
        --отображаем ТОЛЬКО ТЕ данные, где количество записей
        --более или равно 3,то есть группа состоит из 3 последовательных дат (или более 3)
```

Comment: Работает! Большое спасибо)

Comment: Да интересно проверьте на переходящих датах по месяцам, как это будет работать?

Comment: не работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/272bf/1

Comment: а это работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/272bf/2

Comment: Aziz Umarov, спасибо)).Очевидно надо было всего лишь исправить строку, где вместо DayOfDate-Number указать DATEADD(DAY,-Number,visit_date), то есть при расчете номера группы указывать саму дату, а не только день.Я уже исправила этот нюанс)

Answer (score 1):

Наверное можно сделать соединениями

```
WITH [Data] AS(
  SELECT id,
         visit_date,
         people_count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY visit_date) [rowNumber]
  FROM visit),
Data1 as(SELECT Data.id, DataNext.id as id1, DataNextPlus.id as id2 FROM Data
   inner join Data as DataNext 
    on Data.rowNumber = DataNext.rowNumber + 1
   inner join Data as DataNextPlus
    on Data.rowNumber = DataNextPlus.rowNumber + 2
WHERE Data.people_count > 100 and 
      DataNext.people_count > 100 and 
      DataNextPlus.people_count > 100)
Select distinct data.* From data
Inner join data1
 On data.id = data1.id or data.id = data1.id1 or data.id = data1.id2
```

Comment: Близко, но выводит только два дня подряд

Comment: Да 2 подряд значит 4 дня если что

Comment: Щя напильником поработать

Comment: А если так попробовать?

Comment: Выборка получилась большая, после добавления DISTINCT в последний SELECT прям почти как надо, но все таки зацепило последовательность из двух дней

Comment: Интересно как таки попалась она